# How to assign a data source that will work on any computer if I copy the project there?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\RM\\Desktop\\WinForm\\WinForm\\winform.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
```

How to assign data source that will work on any computer if I copy the project there. As a specific path is set I have to change that path when I move this project to another computer. How to set a path that can work on any computer without changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to define the data source in relative terms, either using current directory or by setting the data directory explicitly.

Here's the code to use the data source path with a defined data directory:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\winform.mdb;Persist Security Info=True";
```

Once you've set that, you can actually set your data directory from inside your code.  The code below will get the current application path and then set that to the data directory.  You could also make this any other directory (or subdirectory) that you like.

```
var exeLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string exePath = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exeLocation));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", exePath);
```

**Update:** Per Steve's comment below, you may not always be able to write to the program's current directory (i.e. if the program is installed in "Program Files" and the application is not run with administrative permissions), so better approach in this case would be to have a designated data directory that you know will be writable.

Comment: A database requires read/write access to its files. Usually the folder where the application is installed has no such access available. I prefer to have the database stored in the ProgramData folder under the application subfolder

Comment: @Steve That's a fair point, but the original question shows the program operating out of the user profile, so in this case it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Since you're already using it, you could get the path from  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead of `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, which requires a reference to `System.Reflection`.